# Why in THREE.js the arithmetic expression in Object3D.translateX isn't evaluated as expected or Vector.copy doesn't work correctly in animate loop?

Tags: animation, graphics, three.js, 3d, copy

I'm trying to move an object called "car" via the dat.gui. If the user changes the x value using the dat.gui slider, the car should move along the x-axis of its local coordinate system.
here I have copied the part of the code that is causing me problems:

```
var m = new THREE.Vector3;
m.copy(car.position);
if (changed.key=='X') car.translateX(changed.value-car.worldToLocal(m).x);
```

My problem is that the expression in car.translateX always evaluates to the value that is in changed.value. The part after the minus has no effect at all or maybe is permanently 0. I have printed the values ​with console.log and the values ​​of car.position.x and m change in each step, but the subtraction still delivers in every step only the result that is already in changed.value anyway. Can someone help me and tell me why this happens?
Unfortunately, I am absolutely stuck.

Answer (score 1):

> car.worldToLocal(m)

I'm afraid this piece of code makes no sense since `car.position` (and thus `m`) already represents the car's position in local space.

Instead of using `translateX()` you achieve the same result by modifying `car.position` directly:

```js
car.position.x = changed.value;
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response @Mugen87. I've experimented with rotations and translations and always looked at the values ​​of .position.
If I rotate an object around the z-axis by pi / 2, the y-axis points in -x-direction and the x-axis in y-direction. If I now call translateX (2), the position is x = 0, y = 2, z = 0, so it is not at x = 2. I.e. the value of position is the value that the point has in the parent coordinate system.
If I now write car.position.x = changed.value, my figure is not shifted along the x-axis from the local coordinate system but is set to -2 along the y-axis.

Comment: So the car does not move in the desired direction because it does not move along the axis according to I had previously rotated the coordinate system, but still as the axes are from the parent. That's why I tried to implement it that way. Do I have a mistake here or do I misunderstand the definition of local and global coordinate systems?

Comment: If you want to translate something in world space, you have to transform the object's position into world space, translate along the respective axis and then convert the new position back to local space. So you probably want to work with [Object3D.localToWorld()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=obje#api/en/core/Object3D.localToWorld) first.

Comment: Yes. I have a scene which is my root, my worldSpace. And Car is a child of Scene. Since .position of car contains the coordinates of the point* in the parent coordinate system and this is the world coordinate system, I already have the position in world coordinates. But I wanted to do the translation along the X-axis in the local space.
*(By the way, by "point" I mean the origin of the local coordinate system of car.)